# Does translation operator preserve norm on weighted Lebesgue spaces?

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

We define weighted Lebesgue norm as follows:

$\|f\|_{L_{w}^p}^p= \int_{\mathbb R^d} |f(x)|^p w(x) dx$

where $w$ is some nonnegative weight function (e.g., $ w(x)= (1+|x|^2)^{1/2}$ )

Fix $y\in \mathbb R^d,$ $T_yf(x)=f(x-y)$ (translation operator), we know that $\|T_yf\|_{L^p}=\|f\|_{L^p}$

> My Question is: Can we say that  $\|T_yf\|_{L_w^p}=\|f\|_{L_w^p}$?

Comment: Build yourself an example in $d=1$. Take $f(x)=\mathbf 1_{[0, 1]}(x)$ and let $y\to \infty$. What happens to the integral $\|T_y f\|_{L^p_w}^p$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe so, here is my proposition.

We know

$$\|T_yf\|_{L^p}=\|f\|_{L^p}$$

This is because the Lebesgue Measure is translationally invariant.
i.e. 
$$E\in \mathcal{M}\implies \mu(x+E)=\mu(E)$$

Where $\mathcal{M}$ is the sigma algebra of measurable sets.

This does not hold for all measures.

So in our case let's consider the following counterexample.

Let $E\in \mathcal{M}$ and say $\mu(E)<\infty$ and let's also assume that E is a bounded set.

Consider $\chi_E$ the characteristic function defined on E. 
I think we can agree that 
$$\chi_E\in L^p$$ and $$\chi_E\in L^p_w$$
If we apply $T_y$ to our function then $\|\cdot\|_{L^p_w}$ will not be preserved because our weight varies with position and so the measure of E will not be translation invariant.

This is just what my intuition says, perhaps someone else can elaborate a little more.

Take care.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with this answer, it is only a bit too long in my opinion. The same thing could be said in a couple of lines, with an explicit example. But this is correct.